# Laravel Field 'id' doesn't have a default migration?

Tags: mysql, laravel

When i migrate my database i get this error. In ubuntu i dont get this error. But if i  migrate/import to the server or MAC i get this bellow error.
This is my users model. Fillable stuf

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'user_type_id', 'verified',
    ];
```

I tired to **migrate:refresh**

```
Rolling back: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Rolled back:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table


 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `migrations` ('migration', 'batch') valu
 es (2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table, 1))



 [PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

I've changed  `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` in AppServiceProvider.php and it never worked.

Comment: Post your migration code.

Comment: In table, you try making id field as auto increment. Without showing the code, cant say much.

Answer (score 1):

In your migration you should use increments field:

```
Schema::create('YourTable', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        // More fields
});
```

Answer (score 0):

id in your migration file is like: `$table->integer('id');` which is not `auto-incrementing` so you either make it auto increment or add it to `$fillable` array and specify the `id` on each insert.

I recommend the first approch

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
    });
```